# Lightdm not running when turning computer on

Tags: lightdm

I have ubuntu 16.04 and i typed `sudo service lightdm stop` in terminal when setting trying to find xorg.config file. After that i managed to turn lightdm on but now lightdm wont run when i turn the computer on. I can turn lightdm on from virtual consolw by typing sudo service lightdm start`,but i have to do it every time i shut down the computer.

If i put the computer on standby mode i don't have to set it from virtual console.

Can you help me so i don't have to run that piece of code everytime i turn computer on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you somehow *disabled* lightdm on boot.

I would advise start using *systemd* better than *upstart scripts* for that kind of tasks.

With `sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service`, lightdm should be re-enabled *(recreates the pertinent symlink)*.

You can *(maybe should)* start using `sudo systemctl enable|disable|start|stop|reload|restart servicename.service` as replacement of `sudo service servicename start|stop|reload|restart`.

If lightdm still doesn't work, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

At last, if you still experience the same problem, you'll need to change the settings manually either by using lightdm-set-defaults or manually editing */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf*.

Open *lightdm.conf* and check you have the following settings under `[SeatDefaults]` *(if not add it)*:

`user-session=ubuntu`

`greeter-session=unity-greeter`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I tried  `sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service` and got ´Synchronizing state of lightdm.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lightdm´

But the problem occurs still, the screen is black when i turn the computer on.

Comment: Seems you touched anything else. Answer updated with full instructions.